# fatal: Not a git repository: '<repo path>'

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

The repo had been working fine until I tried to view the source with VS Code though NFS.

Git status and checkout work, but pretty much nothing else. I'm not able to push anything to remote, and there's a lot of local changes. How should I go about repairing the repo (hoping for not having to move diffs as last resort)? Thanks in advance!

```
$ git status
On branch <branch>
...
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git log
fatal: Not a git repository: <repo path>

$ echo $GIT_DIR
<repo root correct>

$ ll -dn $GIT_DIR/.git
drwxr-xr-x 7 <UID correct> <GID correct> 4.0K Sep  9 14:55 <repo root>/.git
```

Comment: If `git status` works, `git log` should work, and vice versa. The usual case is something getting messed up with the file named `.git/HEAD`, but that would break `git status` too.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I go about repairing the repo?

You can check first if copying the all repo to a local folder (ie removing the NFS access) will result in a working repo.

Another approach is to clone that repo again, locally, and report your current work in progress to it.

Once you have a working repo locally, you can try and clone it again through your NFS share.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access rights to files within the `.git` directory (`ls -lR .git`)

Depending on the git commands which were executed by VS Code through NFS, it is pretty possible that only *some* files ended up with bad rw access.